# delete pandas dataframe row if every value is equal

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a pandas dataframe which has a row containing float values and all the values are equal in the row, how do I delete that row from the dataframe?

Comment: It is always helpful to provide a snapshot of the data along with some code you tried

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) for test number of unique values per rows with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for filter out unique rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.nunique(axis=1).ne(1)]
```

Or test if not equal first column and test if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[df.ne(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
```

If you want to remove all rows and all columns with the same values solution should be changed for test columns with `loc` and `axis=0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,4,4,4,4,4],
         'C':[4,4,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[4,4,5,7,1,0],

})

print (df)
   B  C  D
0  4  4  4
1  4  4  4
2  4  9  5
3  4  4  7
4  4  2  1
5  4  3  0

df2 = df.loc[df.nunique(axis=1).ne(1), df.nunique(axis=0).ne(1)]
```

And for second solution:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.ne(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).any(axis=1), df.ne(df.iloc[0], axis=1).any(axis=0)]
```

---

```
print (df2)
   C  D
2  9  5
3  4  7
4  2  1
5  3  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) over `axis=1` (per row):

```
# Example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2,3],
                   'Col2':[2,2,5],
                   'Col3':[4,2,9]})

   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     2     4
1     2     2     2  # <-- row with all same values
2     3     5     9
```

```
df[df.diff(axis=1).fillna(0).ne(0).any(axis=1)]

   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     1     2     4
2     3     5     9
```